# Stack Exchange chat page is the same as Stack Overflow Chat?

Tags: support, chat

The best way to explain this is to show you:

https://chat.stackexchange.com:

> [image: Stack Exchange Chat]

As you can see, the logo is not right. Also, the font is orange, and all the logos on the chat rooms are one of Stack Overflow.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com:

> [image: Stack _Overflow_ Chat]

The difference is that below "Rooms", the SE chat says it is about the SE network, while in the SO chat, it states events coming soon about programming.

I do not remember the SE chat page being like that, so something must have happened, unless I am wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome for Windows 10. I see the correct icons on both chat servers. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard I am using Chrome on iOS, as you should be able to infer from the screenshots. Also, is this how the page should normally look?

Comment: Nope. For me chat.SO looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFAzb.png) and chat.SE looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBxEd.png).

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard you have to be on the "site" tab on Stack Exchange chat in order to see this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's 3 chat servers - SO has its own set of chat. MSE has its own chat and the rest of the SE network has its own chat.

The SE network chat basically has folks with 10k *anywhere* on the network with chat moderation powers. SO and MSE are restricted to their own sites - as a community moderator on SU - I have full powers there, and likewise on MSE as one of the community mods here. I barely have chatting powers on SO.

*Confusingly* you can have rooms with MSE and SO as a parent site on the main SE chat...

So, no, you're not going mad.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Journeyman Geek said, there is also an option to filter all chat rooms based on their parent site.

When you click on the *site* tab (IIRC the default one), you will be shown only chat rooms associated with the currently selected filter site<sup>1</sup>.

The default filter is your chat parent site<sup>2</sup>.

You can select the filter site by clicking on the "(more sites)" link below the tab widget:

[image: The site switcher]

Which site you choose, influences the design the site gets, so if I select *Science Fiction and Fantasy*, I see this design:

[image: Chat with SFF-design]

And when I choose *Stack Overflow*, this design appears:

[image: Chat with SO-design]

---

<sup>1</sup>Which site a room appears is associated with, can be chosen when creating a new room with your parent site as the default
<sup>2</sup>To set/change the parent site, go to your [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev6BR.png).